# Datastax-agent error - IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: 130

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

We have a Cassandra cluster with ssl monitored by Datastax-agent/Opscenter.

Every minutes the datastax-agent produces this error :

```
ERROR [cassandra-processor-4] 2016-05-19 13:44:21,001 Error when proccessing cassandra calljava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: 130
ERROR [cassandra-processor-2] 2016-05-19 13:45:22,185 Error when proccessing cassandra calljava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: 130
ERROR [cassandra-processor-2] 2016-05-19 13:46:23,359 Error when proccessing cassandra calljava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: 130
ERROR [cassandra-processor-3] 2016-05-19 13:47:24,459 Error when proccessing cassandra calljava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: 130
ERROR [cassandra-processor-1] 2016-05-19 13:48:25,529 Error when proccessing cassandra calljava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: 130
ERROR [cassandra-processor-4] 2016-05-19 13:49:26,604 Error when proccessing cassandra calljava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: 130
ERROR [cassandra-processor-3] 2016-05-19 13:50:27,691 Error when proccessing cassandra calljava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: 130
ERROR [cassandra-processor-1] 2016-05-19 13:50:27,691 Error when proccessing cassandra calljava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: 130
ERROR [cassandra-processor-4] 2016-05-19 13:51:27,807 Error when proccessing cassandra calljava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for byte: 130
```

Despite this error, Opscenter indicates that all the agents are connected and everything seems to work normally.

Here is the address.yaml conf file :

```
stomp_interface: <hostname-opscenter>
hosts: ["<hostname-cassandra-node>"]
use_ssl: 1
```

Comment: FI: datastax-agent version: 5.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a serialization bug when recording some histograms. This has been fixed and will be resolved in next version. Its something you can ignore safely.